# jQuery UI checkbox not affecting the checked attributed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm studying the checkbox at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox).

Q: Why does clicking on the toggle button not toggle the "checked" attribute?

Comment: How are you verifying this? Could you provide some sample code exhibiting the problem?

Comment: I'm just using Firebug and examining the jQuery UI example in their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at Firebug isn't going to be enough to determine if the [`checked` property on the relevant DOM element](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025) is set to `true` or `false`. In other words, just because the source viewer in Firebug doesn't show `<input checked='checked' />` doesn't mean the checkbox isn't checked.

For the official explanation, check out the W3 link above. Under the documentation for the `checked` property, you'll see:

> When the type attribute of the element has the value "radio" or
>   "checkbox", this represents the current state of the form control, in
>   an interactive user agent. **Changes to this attribute change the state
>   of the form control, but do not change the value of the HTML checked
>   attribute of the INPUT element.**

For the proper test, type the following in the console after clicking the button a few times:

```
$("#check").prop("checked");
```

Also, if you submit a form and the checkbox is a *successful control*, I promise the correct value of `#check` will be posted.